# SQL Search Query ,how to assign weight to each input parameters and how to order the results by weight of input parameters,

Tags: sql

I have a table [Car] with CarID,Make,Mode,Version,State,City,MinPrice,Maxprice, as 8 columns.
I want to implement a search algorithm with 4 input parameters as Make,City,MinPrice,MaxPrice

How to assign weight to each input parameter.

Please advise me to write search query which gives AND results first and then OR results to follow AND results based on the weight of 4 input parameters.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide sample data, sample input parameters and expected output.

Comment: Explain this sentence clearly: "Please advise me to write search query which gives AND results first and then OR results to follow AND results based on the weight of 4 input parameters." It is hard to understand what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select * from [Car]
where Make = @Make or 
      City = @City or 
      MinPrice >= @MinPrice or 
      MaxPrice <= @MaxPrice
order by 
      case when Make = @Make then 3 else 0 end + 
      case when City = @City  then 2 else 0 end + 
      case when MinPrice >= @MinPrice then 1 else 0 end + 
      case when MaxPrice <= @MaxPrice then 1 else 0 end
      desc
```

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks a lot.It worked.The part of AND results is fine. Coming to part of OR results,I want give first preferene to Make input parameter,then second preference to City.I mean the display oder of OR results.In the OR results,I mean each result row,for example,In the result row if Make is equal to input parameter Make,then that result row should immediately get displayed first in the OR results.In the result row if the Make is not equal to input parameter Make and if City is equal to input city,then this result row should get displayed second in OR results... please Advise me. Thanks.

Comment: would like to add this for the above comment,the weight of Make is more than city. the weight of city is more than MinPrice.For example     Weight of Make=3,                                                     weight of city=2,                                                        weight of MinPrice=1,                                                weight of MaxPrice=1,                                               so that i get the results in the required order, thanks

Comment: @ChethanBabuR: Hi Chethan, the answer is to amend the `then` values in the `order by` `case` clauses to match the desired weightings - I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Mark.. Thanks a lot for your reply.I got the required result. thanks.